# Could anyone help me with the meaning of the words in bold?

Tags: phrase-meaning, metaphors

Mr.Pneumonia was not what you would call a chivalric old gentleman. A **mite of a little woman** with **blood thinned** by California zephyrs was hardly fair game for the red-fisted, short-breathed old duffer. But Johnsy he smote; and she lay, scarcely moving, on her painted iron bedstead, looking through the small **Dutch window-panes** at the blank side of the next brick house.

---

Is Dutch windowpanes refer to the glass of window that made in Netherlands?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mite" is a metaphor. It is literally a tiny bug related to spiders. It means the woman is **small**.

"Blood thinned" (or "thin-blooded") is a colloquial phrase which implies **weakness**. With the reference to pneumonia, I would assume the woman is **frail** or **sickly**.

["Dutch windows"](http://standplaatswereld.nl/2009/12/10/what-dutch-windows-tell/) are a kind of window. They are large (relative to the room they are part of), decorated, and usually not covered by curtains or blinds. Describing them as small probably indicates they are modest in size but still decorated in the typical fashion.

Comment: Actually, it's important that they're described as **Dutch window-panes**.  The Dutch style is to have many small window panes, separated by [muntins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muntin), within the larger window.